# How can i escape double quotes in asp

Tags: asp.net

How can i escape double quotes in the following asp code.

```
Text="<span class='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Country_Status")) ? "glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up":"glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down") %>'></span>"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In most cases, it is much easier to do this in the code-behind in the ItemDataBound event. Also, building HTML into the `Text` of an ASP.NET control isn't advisable (you can do it in something like a `Literal` though).

Answer (score 0):

Try `&quot;` instead of `"` where you need it.  So something like:

```
     Text="<span class='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Country_Status")) ?
     &quot;glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up&quot;:&quot;
     glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down&quot;) %>'></span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you're using. I'll assume C#.

If you're using C#, you escape a character with a \ before it in a string.

So escaping a quote would be `\"` in C#. You may be better off doing this in codebehind and using a single quote instead.